# .NET 4.0 won't install on my Mac

Tags: mojave, wine, steam

So, I go to the install components tab for steam and install .NET 4.0, but it doesn't work; it just says "Please wait while .NET Framework 4.0 is installed..." and goes on forever, which makes my MacBook blow air.  I have to manually kill the process in Activity Monitor. I installed dinput just fine so I think its just a problem with .NET 4.0.

Don't know if this will help: https://pastebin.com/dxyU7WwW

I'm using Wine 3.17

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing it manually? By manually, I mean taking dotNet4.0 from another source other than the WINE build PlayOnMac tries to download and installing it as a separate program but on the same PlayOnMac virtual hard drive Steam is installed on? I've had success with this before.